# MYSQL CASE statement in WHERE clause AND additional LEFT OUTER JOIN with IS NULL in WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've set up a simple fiddle to demonstrate my example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7c813/7/0

There is a people table and an answers table. For the purposes of demonstration they've been reduced to the columns needed for this particular query.

My ideal final result set looks similar to the one in the above fiddle.

```
person_id, name, took_form_14, took_form_15
```

What I'd like, however, is to only have the people that took EITHER form 14 OR form 15, OR NEITHER form 14 NOR form 15, but not who took both (true in both columns).

I figured I could use an additional `WHERE` clause to simple return those results where they are `NULL`, but I can't seem to nail the syntax for removing the cases where took_form_14 AND took_form_15 are both true.

When I tried, I got this error:

```
Invalid use of group function: 
SELECT p.*, 
MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 14 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS took_form_14, 
MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 15 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS took_form_15 
FROM people p 
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.person_id = p.id 
WHERE( 
    MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 14 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) = 'false' 
    OR 
    MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 15 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) = 'false' ) 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also, can someone explain why I need to use the MAX function ahead of my case statement, or I get different results?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a HAVING and not an additional where.

Something like

```
SELECT p.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 14 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS took_form_14,
  MAX(CASE WHEN form_id = 15 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS took_form_15
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.person_id = p.id OR a.person_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING took_form_14 = 'false' OR took_form_15 = 'false'
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7c813/22)

Comment: This seems to result in the correct result set. Thanks for making me run off and check out the mysql docs on HAVING now! Appreciate the quick response. Any idea on why the MAX function changes the result set? I'll look it up in the docs, but generally human answers are a bit more digestible.